# BitShift enum condition with int

Tags: c#, enums

This is mostly academic in nature. Just attempting to understand why this doesnt work and how to do it properly.

I store in my database a 0 1 or 2 where each represent a different status flag. (this cant be changed its in production)

In my code I have an enum

```
public enum Status{
    Active = 0,
    Voided = 1<<0,
    Refunded = 1<<1
}
```

What I want to do is turn the database value into my enum with as little code as possible.

I am sure I could do some crazy walk through like this

```
If(dbValue == 0)
   return Status.Active;
else if(dbValue == 1)
   return Stats.Voided;
```

... and so on

But I was curious if there was a simpler way.

Basically how do I quickly convert between an Int32 and a bit shifted enum with as little code as possible.

I tried doing this

```
   return dbVal | Status.Active;
   return 1 << Convert.Int32(dbValue);
```

and a couple other variations but nothign seems to work/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the enum you show, the following will work:

```
int dbValue = ...;
var status = (Status)dbValue;
```

If the database value can only take one of three values - 0 (Active), 1 (Voided), 2 (Refunded) - then it would probably be clearer to make your enum the following equivalent.

```
public enum Status
{
    Active = 0,
    Voided = 1,
    Refunded = 2
}
```

The bit shifts you use suggest a bit field, but that's not what you actually are dealing with. It wouldn't make sense to have `Status.Voided | Status.Refunded;`.

Comment: So for future reference if I want to use a bit shift enum what value SHOULD be stored in the database?

Comment: @AMR I don't entirely understand the question.

Comment: If I want to use the bit shifting format, say with 100 different enum options. What is the proper way to store that value in the database?

Comment: because right now I am just basically storing the index of the enum option I want

Comment: @AMR I guess I don't understand the motivation for a bit shifting format in the first place. Typically that is done if someone decides they want to compactly represent a small array of booleans. Consider for example `enum ChemType { None = 0, Caustic = 1 << 0, Explosive = 1 << 1, Poisonous = 1 << 2, Flammable = 1 << 3 }`. I could now says `ChemType c = ChemType.Caustic | ChemType.Flammable;` to represent a caustic and flammable chemical type. But you don't appear to be storing a bit field like this. I still don't understand the question.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it was academic. I saw in production code bit shifting used for privileges. I wanted to learn more about it.